# No he podido instalar Angular cli

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli

Alguien me puede ayudar urgente por favor, no me quiere instalar Angular CLI por ningún medio, este es el error que me sale

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /usr/lib/node_modules npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules npm ERR!
>   code EACCES npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! Error:
>   EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  {
>   [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'] npm
>   ERR!   stack: npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'', npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code:
>   'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/usr/lib/node_modules' } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The operation was
>   rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not
>   have the permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please
>   double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing
>   directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again as
>   root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/felipe/.npm/_logs/2019-08-07T03_09_40_180Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

No tienes permisos de acceso en la carpeta `/usr/lib/node_modules`

Deberías revisar los permisos de esa carpeta y asignar los correctos.

Como segunda opción, que debería funcionar (pero no resuelve el problema raíz de los permisos) sería ejecutar el comando precedido de `sudo` para hacerlo con permisos de administrador:

`sudo npm install ...`

Te preguntará por tu contraseña de administrador.